# Login to Zoho CRM with http call

Tags: http, zoho

im trying to automate a login to Zoho CRM. I'm trying to Log In using my data in a http call but looks like it doesn't work. I would like to know if anyone has achieved this.

What I tried:

POST to https://accounts.zoho.com/login

with body:

```
{
 LOGIN_ID: "username", 
PASSWORD: "password", 
IS_AJAX: "true", 
remember :-1,  
servicename: "ZohoCRM"
}
```

The response I get:
Status 200

```
showErrorAndReload('Please\x20reload\x20the\x20page\x20and\x20try\x20again.');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had to do a lot of research and trial and error to figure this one out. Be sure to use **Postman** or something else to test this out for your app.

1. Get the `iamcsr` value from the cookie you receive by visiting `https://accounts.zoho.com/`

   [Here is what the value looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW5ak.png)

   **Note:** You can't reuse or hardcode that value in. Your app has to generate it each login.
2. Insert the following values into the link below and `POST` it.

   `login_id` = your Zoho account login

   `password` = your Zoho account password

   `unix_timestamp` = generate a current unix timestamp with milliseconds

   `iamcsr` = value received from cookie

   The parameter values for `remember`, `servicename`, and `serviceurl` always remain the same.

   `https://accounts.zoho.com/signin/auth?LOGIN_ID={login_id}&PASSWORD={password}&cli_time={unix_timestamp}&remember=2592000&iamcsrcoo={iamcsr}&servicename=AaaServer&serviceurl=https://accounts.zoho.com/u/`

To verify you have successfully logged in you will receive the following response:

`showsuccess('https\x3A\x2F\x2Faccounts.zoho.com\x2Fu\x2F',"",'', '', '-1', 'dXM\x3D');`

This will get you through the login portion and will authenticate you to do further actions assuming your app has stored cookies for the current session.

Answer (score 0):

I made a Php script based on Christian Barahona answer:

1. Get session cookie

```
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36';
$cookie_file_path = 'cookie.txt';

$curl = curl_init('https://accounts.zoho.com/signin?servicename=AaaServer&serviceurl=%2Fu%2Fh/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,
$cookie_file_path);

curl_exec($curl);
```

2. Login

```
//Read cookies file
$cookies = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST); 
foreach ($cookies as $cookie){
    $splitted=preg_split('/\s+/',$cookie);
    if($splitted[0]=="accounts.zoho.com"){
        if($splitted[sizeof($splitted)-2]=="iamcsr"){
            $iamscr=$splitted[sizeof($splitted)-1];
        }
    } 
} 
//return current unix timestamp in milliseconds
function milliseconds() {
    $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
    return ((int)$mt[1]) * 1000 + ((int)round($mt[0] * 1000)); 
} 

$postValues = array(
    'LOGIN_ID' => '*******',
    'PASSWORD' => '*******',
    'cli_time'=> milliseconds(),
    'remember'=> '2592000',
    'iamcsrcoo'=> $iamscr,
    'servicename'=> 'AaaServer',
    'serviceurl'=> 'https://accounts.zoho.com/u/h' 
);
$postValuesFormatted = http_build_query($postValues);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.zoho.com/signin/auth'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postValuesFormatted); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);

curl_exec($curl);
```

3. Curl any page while logged

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.zoho.com/u/h');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```